# The meaning of the GraphId column in the Node tables in sqlserver 2017 Graph database

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases, sql-server-2017

I want to know what is the Meaning and specially the usage of the Column
GraphID when creating a node table in the sql server 2017 graph database.
actually i searched and googled it but I could not find a practical answer to my question . 
you can see the GraphID here :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This column is the internal graph_id column of the graph and cannot be queried. It’s probably used internally by SQL Server to manage graph data in the proper way

Within every Node Table this implicit identity column will be generated as a Graph_Id, which name will contain internal graph_id column with another hex string automatically added to it. You can refer to the [link](http://www.nikoport.com/2017/06/03/sql-graph-part-i/) for more information and examples.